# PHP auto method args to namesake property?

Tags: php, eclipse

I often do this when making classes and found it to be really bothersome, especially when I have classes with 20 or so properties.

is there a way to shorten this:

```
class SomeClass {
    public $property1, $property2, $property3;

    function __construct($property1, $property2, $property3) {
        $this->property1 = $property1;
        $this->property2 = $property2;
        $this->property3 = $property3;
    }
}
```

I really googled everything that hit my mind but haven't found any results, so it probably isn't possible?

If it isn't possible to do it programmatically, is there a way I can make Eclipse PDT automatically write down this code for me on my request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this into your constructor

```
$reflector = new ReflectionClass(__CLASS__);
$parameters = $reflector->getMethod(__FUNCTION__)->getParameters();
$variables = get_class_vars(__CLASS__);
foreach($parameters as $parameter)
{
    foreach ($variables as $variable => $value)
    {
        if ($parameter->name == $variable)
        {
            $this->$variable = ${$parameter->name};
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I especially like **break** in foreach which would allow me to place additional parameters which shouldn't be assigned to properties!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use an array

```
class SomeClass {
    public $property

    function __construct($property) {
        $this->property = $property;
    }
}
b = new SomeClass(array($property1, $property2, $property3));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for:

```
class MyTestClass
{
    public $att1, $att2, $att3;

    function __construct($att1, $att2, $att3)
    {
         $class = new ReflectionClass('MyTestClass');
         $construct = $class->getConstructor();
         foreach ($construct->getParameters() as $param)
         {
            $varName = $param->getName();
            $this->$varName = ${$param->getName()};
         }

    }

    function confirm()
    {
        print "att1 = ". $this->att1 . "<br>";
        print "att2 = ". $this->att2 . "<br>";
        print "att3 = ". $this->att3 . "<br>";
    }

}



// Example for non-class functions
function init($a, $b, $c)
{

    $reflector = new ReflectionFunction('init');

    foreach ($reflector->getParameters() as $param) {
        print $param->getName(). " = ".${$param->getName()}."<br>";
    }

}

init ("first", "second", "third");
$testClass = new MyTestClass("fourth", "fifth", "sixth");
$testClass->confirm();
```

Results:

```
a = first
b = second
c = third
att1 = fourth
att2 = fifth
att3 = sixth
```

Comment: Thanks, good answer, upvoted. Accepted the other one because it was posted earlier :)